# Robustly parse Wikitables with rowspan and colspan into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, html, html-table, screen-scraping

Consider wikipedia tables for [DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_party_strength_in_Washington,_D.C.) and for [Wisconsin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_party_strength_in_Wisconsin) or the [cricket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_England_Test_cricket_records) example from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763891/what-should-i-do-when-tr-has-rowspan). I want to parse the above tables into a `Pandas` `DataFrame` for further processing, ideally using `BeautifulSoup` as that's what I am familiar with.

I have tried all parsers I could find on StackOverflow yet could not find one that even after retooling was able to parse correctly all three of the above tables. The tables of concern have the following essence:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">year</th>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th colspan="2">col2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">aaa</td>
        <td rowspan="2">bbb</td>
        <td rowspan="1">ccc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2017</td>
        <td rowspan="2">ddd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2018</td>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td colspan="1">col2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The parsers of concern fail to correctly track the rowspan and colspan attributes thus only parsing part of the table correctly and the rest being shifted into a jumble. Is there a robust parser than can handle the above example AND the Wikitable examples?

Comment: "Is there an html attribute or info elsewhere that can reveal this info?" `rowspan` and `colspan`

Comment: thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot; Say for 2001, the `rowspan` says `"2"` for all entries which doesn't quite reveal their corresponding column. There is no `colspan` atttribute. Could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: Are you suggesting that to build the table, I must keep track of `rowspan` entries from the top and build it top down?

Comment: `<td colspan="3" rowspan="2">` means that particular cell spans 3 columns and 2 rows (i.e. it is 3 columns wide and 2 rows tall). If either `rowspan` or `colspan` is unspecified, the value is 1.