# How to grab all tr elements from a table and click on a link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to figure out how to print all tr elements from a table, but I can't quite get it working right.

Here is the link I am working with.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_Senate

Here is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_Senate"

html = requests.get(link).text

# If you do not want to use requests then you can use the following code below
# with urllib (the snippet above). It should not cause any issue."""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
res = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "fn"})
for r in res:
    print("Name: " + r.find('a').text)
    table_body=soup.find('senators')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols=row.find_all('td')
        cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        print(cols)
```

I am trying to print all `tr` elements from the table named `'senators'`.  Also, I am wondering if there is a way to click on links of senators, like `'Richard Shelby'` which takes me to this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Shelby

From each link, I want to grab the data under `'Assumed office'`.  In this case the value is: `'January 3, 2018'`.  So, ultimately, I want to end up with this:

```
Richard Shelby  May 6, 1934 (age 84)    Lawyer  U.S. House
Alabama Senate  January 3, 1987     2022
Assumed office: January 3, 2018
```

All I can get now is the name of each senator printed out.

Comment: As it may be useful - Propublica has its own, free (CC-BY-NC) API for [retrieving information about the current Congress](https://projects.propublica.org/api-docs/congress-api/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to locate the "Senators" table, you can first find the corresponding "Senators" `label` and then [get the first following `table` element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next):

```
soup.find(id='Senators').find_next("table")
```

Now, in order to get the data row by row, you would have to account for the cells with a "rowspan" which stretch across multiple rows. You can either follow the approaches suggested at [What should I do when <tr> has rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763891/what-should-i-do-when-tr-has-rowspan), or the implementation I provide below (not ideal but works in your case).

```
import copy

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_Senate"


with requests.Session() as session:
    html = session.get(link).text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    senators_table = soup.find(id='Senators').find_next("table")

    headers = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in senators_table.tr('th')]

    rows = senators_table.find_all('tr')

    # pre-process table to account for rowspan, TODO: extract into a function
    for row_index, tr in enumerate(rows):
        for cell_index, td in enumerate(tr('td')):
            if 'rowspan' in td.attrs:
                rowspan = int(td['rowspan'])

                del td.attrs['rowspan']

                # insert same td into subsequent rows
                for index in range(row_index + 1, row_index + rowspan):
                    try:
                        rows[index]('td')[cell_index].insert_after(copy.copy(td))
                    except IndexError:
                        continue

    # extracting the desired data
    rows = senators_table.find_all('tr')[1:]
    for row in rows:
        cells = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in row('td')]
        print(dict(zip(headers, cells)))
```

---

If you want to, then, follow the links to senator "profile" pages, you would first need to extract the link out of the appropriate cell in a row and then use `session.get()` to "navigate" to it, something along these lines:

```
senator_link = row.find_all('td')[3].a['href']
senator_link = urljoin(link, senator_link)
response = session.get(senator_link)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

# TODO: parse
```

where `urljoin` is imported as:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
```

---

Also, FYI, one of the reasons to use [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) here is to optimize making requests to the same host:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase

---

There is also an another way to get the tabular data parsed - [`.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) from `pandas`. You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html(str(senators_table))[0]
print(df.head())
```

to get the desired table as a dataframe.

Comment: Oh, that's a beautiful thing!  I love the pandas example!!  Thanks for sharing that!!  How does the session.get() & "navigate" work, exactly?  It's the 4th td element (given 0-based indexing).  That's all I can make of it...

Comment: @ryguy72 we are just extracting the link to a senator's page and then following it via `session.get()`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this; I've still got a ton to learn.  I just updated my original post.  Can you take a look at the last part of the script and tell me what's wrong with it?  Thanks.

Comment: @ryguy72 no problem. One thing though: let's avoid solving follow-up problems in the same topic. Please extract this new problem into a new question. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: Ok, I just did it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974473/how-can-i-get-python-to-navigate-to-a-link-and-print-several-data-points-from-th