# How can I get Python to navigate to a link and print several data points from this child link?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at a parent URL, which is this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_Senate

From there, I want to get Python to click several links, all of which are ('td')[3].a['href'].  The first three in the parent URL are:  `'Richard Shelby', 'Doug Jones', and 'Lisa Murkowski'`.  All children links have text that matches this:  `'Assumed office'`.  I want to grab all these dates of `'Assumed office'`.  So, for `'Richard Shelby'` it would be:

```
Assumed office
January 3, 1987
Assumed office
April 10, 2018
```

How can I do that?

For navigating to several different links, I think it will look something like this...

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
senator_link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_Senate"

senator_link = row.find_all('td')[3].a['href']
senator_link = urljoin(link, senator_link)
response = session.get(senator_link)

with requests.Session() as session:
    html = session.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    res = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "nowrap"})
    for r in res:
        print("Assumed Office: " + r.find("span", {'class': 'nowrap'}).text)
```

All I get with that piece of code is this:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: What is the content of `html` after `html = session.get(link).text`?

Comment: Also I would try to run your code but you haven't included all of it for the given context (for example `row` is undefined)

Comment: The `requests` module is easier to work with than `urrlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the table via the id, and then loop over rows, finding the name and the date of `'Assumed office'`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_members_of_the_United_States_Senate').text, 'html.parser')
_, *data = [list(filter(lambda x:x != '\n', [c.text for c in i.find_all('td')])) for i in d.find('table', {'id':'senators'}).find_all('tr')]
final_names = [[(i[1] if len(i) == 7 else i[0]).rstrip(), i[-2].rstrip()] for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[['Richard Shelby', 'January 3, 1987'], ['Doug Jones[d]', 'January 3, 2018'], ['Lisa Murkowski', 'December 20, 2002'], ['Dan Sullivan', 'January 3, 2015'], ['John McCain', 'January 3, 1987'], ['Jeff Flake', 'January 3, 2013'], ['John Boozman', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Tom Cotton', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Dianne Feinstein', 'November 10, 1992'], ['Kamala Harris', 'January 3, 2017'], ['Michael Bennet', 'January 22, 2009'], ['Cory Gardner', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Richard Blumenthal', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Chris Murphy', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Tom Carper', 'January 3, 2001'], ['Chris Coons', 'November 15, 2010'], ['Bill Nelson', 'January 3, 2001'], ['Marco Rubio', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Johnny Isakson', 'January 3, 2005'], ['David Perdue', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Brian Schatz', 'December 26, 2012'], ['Mazie Hirono', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Mike Crapo', 'January 3, 1999'], ['Jim Risch', 'January 3, 2009'], ['Dick Durbin', 'January 3, 1997'], ['Tammy Duckworth', 'January 3, 2017'], ['Joe Donnelly', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Todd Young', 'January 3, 2017'], ['Chuck Grassley', 'January 3, 1981'], ['Joni Ernst', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Pat Roberts', 'January 3, 1997'], ['Jerry Moran', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Mitch McConnell', 'January 3, 1985'], ['Rand Paul', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Bill Cassidy', 'January 3, 2015'], ['John Kennedy', 'January 3, 2017'], ['Susan Collins', 'January 3, 1997'], ['Angus King', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Ben Cardin', 'January 3, 2007'], ['Chris Van Hollen', 'January 3, 2017'], ['Elizabeth Warren', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Ed Markey', 'July 16, 2013'], ['Debbie Stabenow', 'January 3, 2001'], ['Gary Peters', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Amy Klobuchar', 'January 3, 2007'], ['Tina Smith[e]', 'January 3, 2018'], ['Roger Wicker', 'December 31, 2007'], ['Cindy Hyde-Smith[f]', 'April 9, 2018'], ['Claire McCaskill', 'January 3, 2007'], ['Roy Blunt', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Jon Tester', 'January 3, 2007'], ['Steve Daines', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Deb Fischer', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Ben Sasse', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Dean Heller', 'May 9, 2011'], ['Catherine Cortez Masto', 'January 3, 2017'], ['Jeanne Shaheen', 'January 3, 2009'], ['Maggie Hassan', 'January 3, 2017'], ['Bob Menendez', 'January 18, 2006'], ['Cory Booker', 'October 31, 2013'], ['Tom Udall', 'January 3, 2009'], ['Martin Heinrich', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Chuck Schumer', 'January 3, 1999'], ['Kirsten Gillibrand', 'January 26, 2009'], ['Richard Burr', 'January 3, 2005'], ['Thom Tillis', 'January 3, 2015'], ['John Hoeven', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Heidi Heitkamp', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Sherrod Brown', 'January 3, 2007'], ['Rob Portman', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Jim Inhofe', 'November 17, 1994'], ['James Lankford', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Ron Wyden', 'February 6, 1996'], ['Jeff Merkley', 'January 3, 2009'], ['Bob Casey Jr.', 'January 3, 2007'], ['Pat Toomey', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Jack Reed', 'January 3, 1997'], ['Sheldon Whitehouse', 'January 3, 2007'], ['Lindsey Graham', 'January 3, 2003'], ['Tim Scott', 'January 2, 2013'], ['John Thune', 'January 3, 2005'], ['Mike Rounds', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Lamar Alexander', 'January 3, 2003'], ['Bob Corker', 'January 3, 2007'], ['John Cornyn', 'December 1, 2002'], ['Ted Cruz', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Orrin Hatch', 'January 3, 1977'], ['Mike Lee', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Patrick Leahy', 'January 3, 1975'], ['Bernie Sanders', 'January 3, 2007'], ['Mark Warner', 'January 3, 2009'], ['Tim Kaine', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Patty Murray', 'January 3, 1993'], ['Maria Cantwell', 'January 3, 2001'], ['Joe Manchin', 'November 15, 2010'], ['Shelley Moore Capito', 'January 3, 2015'], ['Ron Johnson', 'January 3, 2011'], ['Tammy Baldwin', 'January 3, 2013'], ['Mike Enzi', 'January 3, 1997'], ['John Barrasso', 'June 25, 2007']]
```

Comment: Wow!  That's amazing!!  I thought the solution would look totally different.  There are probably a few different ways to do this, but all I need is one.  Thanks so much!!  Just one more thing.  How does the final_names variable get populated?  Can you add some comments around that?  Also, how does this line work?  list(filter(lambda x:x != '\n'

Comment: @ryguy72 Glad to help! `list(filter(lambda x:x != '\n' ...` removes all occurrences of the newline character in the raw data scraped from the page. `final_names` cleans the latter by removing `\n` at the end of each line and checks to find the locations of the names and dates of office assumption. On the Wikipedia page, senators from the same state are grouped under the same `th` html table tag. That means that the length of the resulting lists will be `6` or `7`, depending on whether the entry has the state included (first `td` col. is not empty).